# How to Center a Div in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Center div in HTML, and CSS???

center a div element in html without using flex-box?
could anyone of you center a div without using flex-box? and grid system?
How to center a div element?
centering a div element in html and css?

Comment: `margin:auto` and `width: X`

Comment: Do you want to center it horizontally, vertically or both?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

without using flex-box, you can use CSS positioning. One common method is to use the position: absolute and transform properties along with top, left, right, and bottom values.

```
<style>
  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 20px;
  }
</style>

<div class="centered">
  <p>This div is centered without using flex-box.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

We can use margin, padding and position to center a div element.

HTML :

```
<div class="horizontal">
 <p>This div is centered without using flex-box.</p>
</div>
```

To Center a `div` element Horizontally :

```
.horizontal {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

To Center a `div` element Vertically:

```
.vertical{
  padding: 70px 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

To Center a `div` element both Horizontally and Vertically:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```